# How to prevent dataloss inside tables while convertig Html to Pdf using iText7?

Tags: itext7, pdfhtml

I am new to iText7. I am using a java program to convert HTML files to PDF. I have used the iText's HtmlConverter to convert html into list of Elements and then create a layout document based on the list of elements.

```
  public static void createPdf(String src, String dest, ConverterProperties properties) throws IOException {  
    List<IElement> elements =
            HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(src), properties);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LEGAL.rotate());

    Document document = new Document(pdf, pdf.getDefaultPageSize(), false);                             
    for (IElement element : elements) {         
        scaleFontSizeRecursively(document, element, (float) 0.68);
        document.add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Pdf output looks good for smaller tables. But if the input html has wider tables then the content is getting cut. Since it is resulting in the dataloss, the solution is not acceptable by the user community.

Is there a way to assign column widths as per content length? Please note that there is lot of empty space between columns, which I believe is being driven from the td width defined in the HTML file. How do I override the column width while generating Pdf from Html using iText7?
Here is the sample input HTML to reproduce the issue.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/print.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="styles/table.css">  
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <table style="width:99.8%; border-collapse:collapse"> 
        <tbody> 
         <tr> 
          <td colspan="21" style="vertical-align:middle"> <p style="text-indent:36pt; text-align:justify; line-height:120%; font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
          <td style="width:45%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:8%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:8%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:8%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:8%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:8%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="width:1%; vertical-align:middle"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> House Income </p> </td> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-left:1.5pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> <strong>$</strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="text-align:right; font-size:10pt"> <strong><a id="Anchor_7195" name="Anchor_7195" ng-click="list($event)">177,934<span class="icon icon-question-mark ato-blue-color" id="CFTO_ELE_ICON"></span></a></strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-left:1.5pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> <strong>$</strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="text-align:right; font-size:10pt"> <strong><a id="Anchor_7196" name="Anchor_7196" ng-click="list($event)">189,582<span class="icon icon-question-mark ato-blue-color" id="CFTO_ELE_ICON"></span></a></strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-left:1.5pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> <strong>$</strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="text-align:right; font-size:10pt"> <strong><a id="Anchor_7197" name="Anchor_7197" ng-click="list($event)">198,377<span class="icon icon-question-mark ato-blue-color" id="CFTO_ELE_ICON"></span></a></strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-left:1.5pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> <strong>$</strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="text-align:right; font-size:10pt"> <strong><a id="Anchor_7198" name="Anchor_7198" ng-click="list($event)">210,103<span class="icon icon-question-mark ato-blue-color" id="CFTO_ELE_ICON"></span></a></strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="padding:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-left:1.5pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> <strong>$</strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-top:1.12pt; padding-bottom:1.5pt; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="text-align:right; font-size:10pt"> <strong><a id="Anchor_7199" name="Anchor_7199" ng-click="list($event)">775,996<span class="icon icon-check ato-green-color" id="CFTO_ELE_ICON"></span><span class="icon-stm-view-formula" id="CFTO_FORMULA_ICON">F&nbsp;</span><span class="icon-stm-wp-reference" id="CFTO_WP_ICON">100011, 100012,100013, 00014,100015,100016</span></a></strong> </p> </td> 
          <td style="border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; vertical-align:bottom"> <p style="font-size:10pt"> &nbsp; </p> </td> 
         </tr>      
        </tbody> 
       </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can scale up the table width to fit the page width. Therefore the table's contents should be scale up to fit the table.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that but that didn't help my current issue. The table width is good but the td contents are getting swallowed while there is lot of white space available in the table.

Comment: Yes of course, because all td and it's contents are parts of table contents.

Comment: Hi, please share sample HTML to reproduce the problem

Comment: @AlexeySubach Please find the html sample I added to the original post today.

Comment: I thought the below iText solution can help me figure out how to text wrap within the td. https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/fit-text-cell But I couldn't come up with the logic to extract text from (Cell)IElement so I can pass it as 2nd param in the below snippet of code. new ClipCenterCellContentCellRenderer(cell, <content of cell>);

Comment: @LakshmiNareddy I cannot reproduce the problem. There is no content loss for me. Which versions of pdfHTML and iText are you using? Please also attach the visual representation of the PDF you are getting and mark out the content that is lost according to you. The CSS files are missing, maybe they are the reason of me not being able to reproduce the problem

Comment: @AlexeySubach Yes, CSS was the culprit. Thanks a lot for trying the html input and sharing the results here. I was able to resolve the issue.